# Linking a folder to another folder (FTP) (LINUX)

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using VSFTP and jailed my users into a certain directory under their home.

Example: /home/$user/downloads

What should i do, if i want to add an additional folder under the /downloads folder that links them to an external folder on another drive?

Answer (score 3):

Symbolic links created using `ln -s` would not solve your problem. Instead use `mount --bind` as suggested in [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/33422).

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can link this folder with a symbolic link.

```
$ ln -s /path/to/drive symbolicfoldername
```

But you still need to set the permissions for the users correct, which maybe your main concern

Comment: thanks Bernhard. Which permission should i set for the user to access said folder?

chown and / or chmod or is there something else?

Comment: chmod should be enough. Supposed all those users are in the same group, you can give this group read/write access to the drive. I am not sure if you are using a common folder for all users, or if you want a separate folder on a per user basis. The principle is the same.

Comment: Tried it Bernhard. Apparently, it works when i'm doing it in the shell. I am able to browse to the designated folder through the symbolic folder. However, if i were to connect to the server via FTP, then the folder is shown, however once i navigate to the folder, its empty. There isn't anything in the folder whereas I could see the contents if I were to connect to it via shell / ssh.